# Unintentional slight arm position change

Tags: unity, camera, movement, first-person-shooter

In the scene I have a capsule with a camera parented and a looking script so when I look down or up the weapon slightly moves forward and then moves back when I look straight forward.

weapon when I look up or down-

[image]

and heres how it looks normally when I look straight forward-

[image]

Anyone knows how I can fix that?

EDIT: Here's how it looks in scene view

[image]

Comment: The movement of gun must be in code or animation , you need to comment out that particular block.

Comment: The gun is parented to the camera so as the camera moves and rotates the gun does too.

Comment: so i don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of hierarchy for the gun and cam?? My second guess is the way the cam moves , due to which it might be causing the back and forth movement of the gun.

Comment: Ok I edited the question

Comment: Sorry mate can't understand the problem

Comment: I would like the gun and the hands to be always visible to the camera as I set it in the scene with always same position but the problem is that as I look up or down (which is done by mouse movement) the thing that happens is showed in the first screen shot which is that the hands and the gun moves a slight distance forward (or appears to be like it) as you can see the difference in the first and the second image (second image is what I want it to constantly look like).My question is how do I keep the position of the arms and gun always the same no matter what is the rotation of the camera.

Comment: Could it be because the origin on the model is in a wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange behaviour in Unity's scale inheritance system. If the parent has a non-uniform scale, when you rotate the child, they deform/stretch like a rubber band.

Try adding an empty child GameObject to Player GameObject and parent the Camera GameObject to empty one, and put the rotation script on Camera. This makes parent of the Camera a uniform-scaled transform, so your rotations won't alter childs' scales.

***Note:*** Make sure the empty GameObject has a uniform scale (ie, 1-1-1).

Answer (score -1):

Parent the gun to the player not the camera. The camera movement is changing the transform of the gun. The capsule for the player still tips forward and backwards so parenting it to the player will alleviate the issue. Otherwise you can code a fixed transform that only allows for verticle and horizontal transform change instead of a forward transform change to follow the camera if you don't want to change what it's parented to.